# How to hide table column with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I need some help. Code below doesn't work just like i needed.

What I want here: With the help of JavaScript I want to hide or make a table column invisible which has **id** *myid*.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  document.getElementById( 'myid' ).style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="myid">x</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: It does work....https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/uxLjLcaz/

Comment: use `$('#myid').hide();` in document ready function

Comment: Your code seems to be working just fine? https://jsfiddle.net/Bjolja/kftfgpke/ darn... too slow

Comment: hello pochen here in my browser not fine

Comment: you should try to get away from using width, border, etc.. on tables. Try to solve this using CSS

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#myid").hide(); 
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you added the jquery in your code.
Your code is working. Check [this FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/rhrow1e9/)

Add this line in your html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i will try and report it to you

Comment: Yes isragrab it works manythanks

Comment: You're welcome @Devisy. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also How does accepting an answer work (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you want to hide entire column by the id of a table cell

something like this

```
<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="myid" class="col0">x</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col0">x</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>



$(document).ready(function(){   
    var className = $('#myid').attr('class')
  console.log(className)
  $('.'+className).hide()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the ids with a classname that repeats in all column. The reason is that ids are unique and you must not duplicate them.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('.myid').hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="myid">x</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="myid">y</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```